# Как игнорировать сломавшийся stdout/stderr?

Tags: python

Есть некий скрипт, который делает важную работу и печатает в консольку всякую красоту, уже не очень важную. Работа достаточно важная, чтобы я перехватывал сигналы `SIGINT` и `SIGTERM` и организовывал и завершал работу скрипта корректно без выкидывания исключений где попало (см. [How to process SIGTERM signal gracefully?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499497))

Однако если взять для примера команду запуска вроде такой:

```
python script.py 2>&1 | tee -a output.log
```

<sup>*(да-да, я в курсе про модуль logging, но вопрос не про него)*</sup>

то при убивании запущенной команды с помощью `Ctrl+C` и `stdout`, и `stderr`, очевидно, умирают. Скрипт ради «gracefully» продолжает работать и, соответственно, продолжает писать в умершие выводы. И тогда — упс:

```
  File "script.py", line 9001, in very_important_function
    sys.stderr.flush()
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

И хрен мне, а не gracefully.

<sup>*(как я получил этот вывод, если stderr умер? Перехватил исключение и записал traceback.format_exc() в текстовый файл :)*</sup>

Как мне сделать так, чтобы broken pipe тотально игнорировался и скрипт продолжал работать как обычно? Чтобы даже исключения не возникало, так как оно всё равно ломает обычный ход работы скрипта, даже если я его перехвачу.

Предполагаю, что нужно перехватить какой-нибудь `SIGPIPE` и что-нибудь сделать с `sys.stdout` и `sys.stderr`, но не уверен, что и как именно.

Теоретически `stdout` и `stderr` не обязательно умирают вместе: если после смерти одного из них можно как-нибудь продолжать использовать другой как обычно, будет вообще прекрасно.

Comment: перехватить `SIGPIPE` и закрыть/переоткрыть поток на `/dev/null`?

Comment: @Fat-Zer может быть, а реально ли в перехвате узнать, кто именно (stdout и/или stderr) умер, чтобы не переоткрывать зазря оба?

Comment: про как определить мыслей нет... но скорей всего не сработает т. к. сигнал посылается на `write ()`

Comment: @Fat-Zer а вообще так чёт не получается: даже если я перехвачу sigpipe и заменю sys.stdout/sys.stderr, старый умерший поток всё равно выкидывает broken pipe (что, впрочем, неудивительно, ибо питон sigpipe по дефолту и так игнорирует, а при вызове `sys.stderr.flush()` sys.stderr здесь в любом случае останется старым и `flush` выкидывает ошибку, как ни заменяй)

Comment: Перспективней выглядит подменить stderr и stdout своими proxy-объектами, которые будут игнорировать/обрабатывать конкретное исключение.

Comment: @Fat-Zer если имеется в виду подмена ещё в начале работы скрипта, то может быть) Хотя это уже monkey patch какой-то

Comment: ничего приличней пока в голову не идёт, но всё лучше, чем try/catch на каждый print()

Comment: Можно начать с запуска вашего скрипта, используя nohup команду. Если не достаточно, чтобы свои костыли не творить, как systemd service попробуйте  запустить. Если хочется своё творить, то перенаправляйте stdout, stderr на уровне file descriptors. [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4675728/4279) (в этом момент стоит рассмотреть: а не перейти ли всё-таки на logging)

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо что-то типа такого:

```
import sys


class SafetyCaller:
   def __init__(self, obj):
      self.__obj = obj

   def __getattr__(self, key): #для всех атрибутов в классе
      attribute = getattr(self.__obj, key)
      if callable(attribute): #если атрибут функция
          def temp(*args, **kwargs): #создадим заглушку
             try:
                 return attribute(*args, **kwargs) #вызовем функцию
             except Exception as ex: #словим все нормальные исключения
                 return None #и ничего не сделаем
          return temp
      return value

   @classmethod
   def patch_stdstream(cls):
       sys.stdout = cls(sys.stdout)
       sys.stderr = cls(sys.stderr)

SafetyCaller.patch_stdstream()
```

Еще можно схватывать все исключения, и возвращять поток выполнения в место броска если нужно. Но это черная магия, лучше таким не заниматься если есть возвожность.